# Can we stream data from Kinesis data stream directly into Amazon s3 or only through Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Can we stream data from Kinesis data stream directly into Amazon s3 or only through Kinesis Firehose.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Kinesis Firehose, you cannot load data directly into S3 from Kinesis Data stream. You can use Kinesis Data stream as a source for the Kinesis Firehose stream which can load data into S3. This is a fairly common architecture where data stream is a source for firehose stream with some custom analytics applications using the data stream.

Comment: Unlike firehose, data stream requires you to create application to read data from the stream. It does not load data to any destination. Both streams have different use cases so you need to identify which one is good for your use case.

Comment: No...I hope data stream can load data to any destination or services...but firehose can load only to S3 or redshift.